# Javascript : unable to read file content using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i was just looking for basic tutorial for js , this is the code i have to read file from a txt file .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xhr= new  XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET","note.txt",false);
    xhr.onreadystatechange= function (){
        if(xhr.readyState===4){
             alert(xhr.responseText);
        } 
        xhr.send(null);
    }

</script>
```

this is in head of a php file and note.txt in same directory , so  i expect to get an alert but  dont get any response , can someone help me with this whats wrong ?

Comment: put xhr.send(null); out of that function

Comment: @ShailendraSharma God bless you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  xhr.onreadystatechange= function (){
        if(xhr.readyState===4){
             alert(xhr.responseText);
        } 
        xhr.send(null);
    }
```

you are calling `send()` in the handler for `onreadystatechange`.